# Insert blank lines in output file C programming

Tags: c

I wrote a simple C program to copy the contact from input file to output one. It works fine. But now I need to insert blank lines between paragraphs in the new file and I can't get how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Here is code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   FILE *fp1,*fp2;
   char ch;


    fp1 =  fopen("input.txt","r");

    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe file was not found.");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp2 =  fopen("output.txt","w");

    if(fp2==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe file was not opened.");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
       ch = fgetc(fp1);

       if(ch==EOF)
          break;
       else
          putc(ch,fp2);
    }

    printf("File copied succesfully!");
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding an extra "\n" to your output? Lines are kind of an "illusion" created for our convenience by text editors, they're really just represented by newline characters.

Comment: What distinguishes a paragraph in your text? Are they indented, or are they indicated in some other manner?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem (I simply wanted to have an empty line in the output between two lines.)

My solution is:

```
    `printf("\n");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can double `\n` characters like this:

```
if(ch==EOF)
    break;
else 
    putc(ch,fp2);

if(ch=='\n')
    putc(ch,fp2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
while(1)
{
   ch = fgetc(fp1);

   if (ch == '\n')
      putc(ch,fp2);

   if(ch==EOF)
      break;
   else
      putc(ch,fp2);
}
```